# How to find the gateway IP address in Linux

Tags: linux, scripting, shell, tcpip, gateway

What command can you use to find the Gateway IP Address (ie. home router address) for eth0 in Linux?

I need to get the IP address from a command line app to use in a shell script.

Comment: Are you looking for the external IP address of the router? In the past I've used a screen scraping script to get that sort of thing from the router setup pages. Most home routers have a browser based setup that is easy to access from the inside. It's hard to give a general solution but you can use curl or wget to fetch the page and then use grep & awk to get the IP address.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question.  Basically, I want to find the gateway IP address that is set to eth0 on a box that has a single ethernet interface.  Coincidentally, this *should be* the IP address of a home, basic, Linksys-type or so, NAT router.  I need it so I can ping it in a shell script.

Comment: Seems more complex than what I need, but a cool, guaranteed-to-work idea though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To print out only the default gw IP:

```bash
route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}'
```

To print out route information on all interfaces:

```
route -n
```

or

```
netstat -rn
```

Comment: Wouldn't UG require the interface to be up? I think just G would be better.

Comment: Wanted to let you know - I'm actually using this answer, but with just a G in the grep pattern;  didn't have iptools on the machine i need to run this on.

Comment: You can save yourself the grep, awk can also filter: `route -n | awk '{if($4=="UG")print $2}'`

Comment: I would suggest something like `route -n|awk '$4~/G/{print $2; exit(0)}'` for the first gateway, but `ip route get IP` is better, because it lists the route which would be really taken to the given IP, which is difficult to find with `route` alone

Comment: `route` is becoming obsoleted.

Comment: `route` and `netstat` are no longer available on Arch. I use `ip route`.

Answer (score 25):

```
ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 dev eth0 | cut -d\  -f3
```

is my entry :)

Comment: I would improve this one:

ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 | awk '{print $3}'

Comment: I dunno... mine's still fewer keystrokes :)

Comment: And `cut` is ~20 times lighter binary than `awk`.

Comment: If I leave off the "dev eth0" does it work for either eth0 or wlan0 ?
(I would try this if I had a long enough lan cable)

Comment: Its worked for me for openwrt os :)

Answer (score 6):

You can get the system's default gateway from the output of `netstat -r` or `route`

Comment: `netstat` is becoming obsoleted.  `ss` is the new replacement.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.199.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U         0 0          0 virbr1
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U         0 0          0 virbr2
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
```

The 0.0.0.0 is your default gateway, pointing to 192.168.1.254 at my place.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the [iproute](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Net:Iproute2) package:

```bash
# get the default route
ip route list | awk ' /^default/ {print $3}'
# get the default route but limit on eth0 (output may be empty)
ip route list dev eth0 | awk ' /^default/ {print $3}'
```

Comment: @sheepsimulator: Unfortunately, this is a bad assumption to make. Supermathie's suggestion is better.

Comment: @Dominic Eidson - Why?  There's only one physical ethernet interface on the machine.

Comment: exactly what is a bad assumption?

Answer (score 4):

Since iproute2 4.14.1, you can also output JSON for a lot of commands.

So this would work:

```bash
ip -j route show 0.0.0.0/0 dev <interface> | jq -r '.[0].gateway'
```

In your case:

```bash
ip -j route show 0.0.0.0/0 dev eth0 | jq -r '.[0].gateway'
```

Note that you need [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this, but depending on your environment that might already be available - I know it was in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The output from route -n or netstat -rn, and search for the destination 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

anyone shorter than this? =)

```
ip r | awk '/^def/{print $3}'
```

Comment: Challenge accepted: `ip r | awk 'END{print $3}'` is three characters shorter.

Comment: nice, but on my local debian/squeeze box with KVM bridges my default gw is in line one. strange but true. So your cool solution doesn`t work everywhere :-/ (anyhow +1 )

Comment: **ip** is not a generic UNIX command - so again it won't work everywhere.

Comment: you are right, but in $Subject stands Linux and not UNIX ;) @David: wow, you have really nice blog!

Comment: `read x x i x< <(ip r g 1)`, result is in variable $i for further use

Answer (score 0):

```bash
netstat -rn |awk '{if($1=="0.0.0.0") print $2}'
```

this will cleanly print the gateway IP. (what would linux scripting be without **awk**?)

Comment: Then you'd have to use **sed** instead... `netstat -rn|sed -n '/^0.0.0.0/{ s/^[0. ]*//; s/ .*$//; p; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the gateway from the interfaces file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
gateway=$(grep -P '^\tgateway' /etc/network/interfaces)
gateway=$(echo ${gateway:9})    # Remove "  gateway "   
echo "gateway = $gateway"
if [ $gateway == "" ]; then
    echo "gateway is blank"
    exit -1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

My one liner command to get the default gateway IP address :

```
route | grep default | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score -2):

Open Terminal on your Linux OS
It’s usually located in the top bar or bottom bar, depending on the Linux distribution you use
Once you have opened the Terminal window, enter the following commands
“ip route | grep default”
Now wait a second for the output and note your default gateway address on the screen
Your gateway address should look something like 192.168.1.1. Once you know it, you can start configuring your router via its web admin panel.

If this didn't fix your network, you may need a new router.